# .NET MAUI Title Bar Minimize and Maximize Button Removal Option

Tags: .net, maui, .net-maui

In .NET MAUI how to remove minimize button and maximize button? in C# we can remove it with MinimizeBox=false and MaximizeBox=false;

[See the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkR1x.jpg)

Comment: Can you visually show me what are you talking about?

Comment: I have added image on my question. Let it check that how can i remove minimize and maximize button from my desktop application.